# How to find minima for non scalar-valued

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I want to find minima.
My code:

```
Formula = N[-{{{0.0, 0, 200.0} - 800.0 {0, 0, Cos[Tetha]}}.{Sin[Tetha] Cos[Phi], 
Sin[Tetha] Sin[Phi], Cos[Tetha]}}]

DensPlot = DensityPlot[Formula, {Tetha, 0, 180}, {Phi, 0, 360}, 
ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["θ0 (Degree)", FontSize -> 16], 
Style["ϕ0 (Degree) ", FontSize -> 16]}, Mesh -> 10];

DensPlot
```

So I plot graph:
[image]

And now i'm trying to find minima. How we can see it is at 70 degree θ0.

```
Minimize[{Formula, 50 <= Tetha <= 100, 0 <= Phi <= 360}, {Tetha, Phi}]
```

I have next mistake:

```
Minimize::objfs: The objective function {0. -1. (200. -636620. Cos[Tetha]) 
Cos[Tetha]} should be scalar-valued. >>
```

If i tried to use FindMinimum:

```
FindMinimum[Formula, {{Tetha, #[[1]]}, {Phi, #[[2]]}}] & /@ 
{{0, 180}, {0, 360}}
```

I have next mistakes:

```
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value {636420.} is not a real number at 
{Tetha,Phi} = {0.,180.}. >>
```

and

```
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value {636420.} is not a real number at 
{Tetha,Phi} = {0.,360.}. >>
```

So my queation How I can find minima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use too many braces:

```
Formula = N[-({0.0, 0, 200.0} - 800.0 {0, 0, Cos[θ]}).{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}];
Minimize[{Formula, 50 <= θ <= 100, 0 <= ϕ <= 360}, {θ, ϕ}]
```

> {-12.5, {θ -> 89.4101, ϕ -> 114.632}}